# The button that I have created does not work. Is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: java, android, button, android-alertdialog

I am building an app in Android studio and basically I want a window to popup when a user clicks the add button. I used the setOnClickListener but when I run the app, nothing happens. Could there possibly something wrong with my code?

Here's my MainActivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button addBtn;
ListView itemListView;
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener;
String dateString = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    itemListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.itemListView);

    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_popup_window, null);
            EditText itemName = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            Button expirationDateBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.expirationDateBtn);

            builder.setView(view)
                    .setTitle("Add Item")
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if (itemName.getText().toString().isEmpty() || dateString == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                        "Item name or expiration date is missing",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            else{
                                //do action
                            }
                        }
                    });

            //when clicked on Expiration Date Btn
            
            //display date on button
```

Comment: It is difficult to analyze your problem with so few code. You should at least consider posting the whole Activity/Fragment class. Also, did you check if the ```onCLick``` method was is called with the debugger (or printing to the stdOut)?

Comment: @JANO I'm new to android studio. How do I check the onClick with the debugger?

Comment: Probably, the answer of @Nicola solves your problem, but nonetheless debugging is an important thing. Best is you google and look into some guide. In short, you can set a breakpoint in your code by clicking on the numbers left of the line of code you want to inspect. Then you start your App by clicking on the debug button (looks like a beatle). Once your program reaches your breakpoint, Android studio switches into Debug mode. From there you can do all kinds of stuff like looking into variables or executing your code line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AlertDialogBuilder` doesn't create and show a new `AlertDialog` implicitly. It only prepares the dialog before explicitly calling `create()` (or you can directly call `show()` if you need to display your dialog in the moment it gets built).
Your code misses the following lines at the end of `onClick()`:

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

or just:

```
builder.show();
```